# How to enable secured-annotations with Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to use `@Secured` annotations for my controller actions. Since I have java based configuration I need to know how I can set the

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

option without the xml file.

**Upate 1:**

I addeed `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` to my security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class LIRSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider())
            .addFilter(cookiePreAuthenticationFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            ;
    }

    ...
}
```

Up on start-up this causes this exception

```
Jul 21, 2014 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 22 more
Jul 21, 2014 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
```

**Update 2:**

After adding

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

I get an other exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager. Please ensure you have configured authentication.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.validateBeanCycle(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:462)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.<init>(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:430)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManagerBean(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:220)
    at com.galexis.lir.config.LIRSecurityConfig.authenticationManagerBean(LIRSecurityConfig.java:36)
    at com.galexis.lir.config.LIRSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88306f96.CGLIB$authenticationManagerBean$3(<generated>)
    at com.galexis.lir.config.LIRSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88306f96$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a4d1ea33.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:293)
    at com.galexis.lir.config.LIRSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88306f96.authenticationManagerBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 77 more
```

Comment: What does the rest of `LIRSecurityConfig` look like?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use the

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
```

annotation, as defined in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#enableglobalmethodsecurity).

Answer (score 11):

You should add also a bean for Manager. Check this out:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "authService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

Important thing is

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well unfortunately this yields an  `FatalBeanException: A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager. Please ensure you have configured authentication.` (see Update 2 above).

Comment: you should never use the MD5 for password hashes.  use BCryptPasswordEncoder

Comment: What is the point of declaring a bean that returns one that is already defined ? 
 Bean
   Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

Comment: @Adelin to declare that object as Bean, otherwise it won't get picked.

Comment: It took me 2 days to find and use this solution. For my (complex) configuration `authenticationManager` in `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` was null without adding `authenticationManagerBean`

Answer (score 6):

Just for the others which will try to solve "A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager. Please ensure you have configured authentication." problem.

The solution is to add the follwing method:

```
@Override
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // do NOT call super.configure() !
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So this did the work :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and().
                withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
```

the important parts are

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and().
                withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
```

Comment: The adding of the `@Bean` for the `AuthenticationManager` did it for me. I did not have a `configureGlobal()` method though I did have a configure method for the AuthenticationManagerBuilder with a UserDetailsService inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Stefan is right, adding

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
```

does the trick.

In my particular situation I had to add to get rid of the excptions.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").authorities("ROLE_USER");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the classes within the annotations

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfigProvider extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }


@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)

Answer (score -1):

I faced the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually activated
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityMetadataSource(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:366) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

To fix this, I added:

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`