# Spring boot with security annotation is not took in consideration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 2 with spring security.

I splitted security for rest and mvc.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/rest/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**",  "/js/**", "/img/**", "/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutHandler())
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

My role in db are

superuser, admin, integrator.

In one of my rest controller, I put

```
@Secured("hasRole('user')")
```

This role don't exist in my application.

I tried with a user who have role: superuser and integrator and that worked...

Same thing with

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user')")
```

Is there any other configuration to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable secured-annotations with Java based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865588/how-to-enable-secured-annotations-with-java-based-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to secure you methods you have to enable ***method security*** by using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class HelloMethodSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityService methodSecurityService() {
        return new MethodSecurityServiceImpl(); //Class managed by Spring
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
          .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

}
```

With the above minimal configuration, methods of the class `MethodSecurityService` can now be secured with method security.

For more customized method security you will need to extend[`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/#custom-method-security).

Check out the official [`docs`](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/).